# Add object to List using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to add N number of list of object to another object by do some operation using google map API but its showing only the Last value in the object.

### Here is my code

```
if (Display.Dispaylist.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var d in Display.Dispaylist)
    {
        requestUri = string.Format("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/xml?placeid=" + d.Placeid + "&radius=7500&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyA0SrtzNyotUjgqI8cwbfYNrRUkdCoACd8");
        WebRequest request2 = WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
        WebResponse response2 = request2.GetResponse();
        XDocument xdoc2 = XDocument.Load(response2.GetResponseStream());
        XElement generalElement1 = xdoc2.Element("PlaceSearchResponse");
        Displayinfo.Dispaylisted = (from e in xdoc2.Descendants("result")
                                    select new DisplacedModelList()
                                    {
                                        Name = Convert.ToString(e.Element("name").Value),
                                        Address = (e.Element("formatted_address") != null ? Convert.ToString(e.Element("formatted_address").Value) : null),
                                        Type = keyword,
                                        PhoneNo = (e.Element("international_phone_number") != null ? Convert.ToString(e.Element("international_phone_number").Value) : null),
                                        WebSite = (e.Element("website") != null ? Convert.ToString(e.Element("website").Value) : null),
                                        Rating = (e.Element("rating") != null ? Convert.ToString(e.Element("rating").Value) : null)
                                    }).ToList<DisplacedModelList>();
        //Displayinfo.Dispaylisted.AddRange();
        //.AddRange(Displayinfo);
        //Displayinfo.Dispaylisted.AddRange(Displayinfo);                                               
    } 
}
return View(Displayinfo);
```

Because each time I am creating new of object so at the end of iteration its show me the last iteration value.
What to do to get the entire list I am new to LINQ..
Thanks for your helping me.

Comment: You aren't adding anything to a `List` in your code. LINQ is for returning information, not modifying objects. If you want to add to a `List`, set the variable to an empty `List`, and create the new objects and add them to the list. If you need to add them from a collection, use a `foreach` loop.

Comment: I cannot see any additions to a list - if you're new to collections in C# then this link helps you with the List in C#. https://www.dotnetperls.com/list-add

Answer (score 0):

In the line of code that sets the Display.Displaylisted property to a new list that you generate using linq. The issue is you set it to a new list for every iteration of your foreach loop. You need check if the list null if it is new it up and if it's not then AddRange passing in your LINQ generated list. I'm on my phone so typing the code is gonna be painful let me know if you need an example and I can get my laptop out

----Edit--- Adding some code as request

Below I've added a comment to show where your code was wrong and hopefully that clears up what you were doing

```
if (Display.Dispaylist.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var d in Display.Dispaylist)
        {
            requestUri = string.Format("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/xml?placeid=" + d.Placeid + "&radius=7500&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyA0SrtzNyotUjgqI8cwbfYNrRUkdCoACd8");
            WebRequest request2 = WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
            WebResponse response2 = request2.GetResponse();
            XDocument xdoc2 = XDocument.Load(response2.GetResponseStream());
            XElement generalElement1 = xdoc2.Element("PlaceSearchResponse");
            //----------------Here you are assigning a new list to the Property for every single iteration of the foreach loop, hence why you only see the last iteration value-----/
            Displayinfo.Dispaylisted = (from e in xdoc2.Descendants("result")
                                        select new DisplacedModelList()
                                        {
                                            Name = Convert.ToString(e.Element("name").Value),
                                            Address = (e.Element("formatted_address") != null ? Convert.ToString(e.Element("formatted_address").Value) : null),
                                            Type = keyword,
                                            PhoneNo = (e.Element("international_phone_number") != null ? Convert.ToString(e.Element("international_phone_number").Value) : null),
                                            WebSite = (e.Element("website") != null ? Convert.ToString(e.Element("website").Value) : null),
                                            Rating = (e.Element("rating") != null ? Convert.ToString(e.Element("rating").Value) : null)
                                        }).ToList<DisplacedModelList>();

        } 
    }
    return View(Displayinfo);
```

**Here is what I think it should be doing**

```
if (Display.Dispaylist.Count > 0)
        {
            //Initialise the list outside of the loop, just do it once 
            Displayinfo.Dispaylisted = new List<DisplacedModelList>();
            foreach (var d in Display.Dispaylist)
            {
                requestUri = string.Format("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/xml?placeid=" + d.Placeid + "&radius=7500&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyA0SrtzNyotUjgqI8cwbfYNrRUkdCoACd8");
                WebRequest request2 = WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
                WebResponse response2 = request2.GetResponse();
                XDocument xdoc2 = XDocument.Load(response2.GetResponseStream());
                XElement generalElement1 = xdoc2.Element("PlaceSearchResponse");
                Displayinfo.Dispaylisted.AddRange(
                    (from e in xdoc2.Descendants("result")
                     select new DisplacedModelList()
                     {
                         Name = Convert.ToString(e.Element("name").Value),
                         Address = (e.Element("formatted_address") != null ? Convert.ToString(e.Element("formatted_address").Value) : null),
                         Type = keyword,
                         PhoneNo = (e.Element("international_phone_number") != null ? Convert.ToString(e.Element("international_phone_number").Value) : null),
                         WebSite = (e.Element("website") != null ? Convert.ToString(e.Element("website").Value) : null),
                         Rating = (e.Element("rating") != null ? Convert.ToString(e.Element("rating").Value) : null)
                     }).ToList<DisplacedModelList>()
                );

            }
        }
        return View(Displayinfo);
```

Comment: Similar to the code you have commented out at the bottom

Comment: Thanks for your helps...But i am new to Linq so plzz....give me some example plzz.. that help me lot better...thanks for your code.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit the answer give me a few minutes and hopefully it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Using your original code, first you need to initialize the `List` before the `foreach`:

```
DisplayInfo.DisplayListed = new List<DisplacedModelList>();
```

Then, inside the `foreach` you add all the returns from the LINQ query:

```
DisplayInfo.DisplayListed.AddRange((from e in xdoc2.Descendants("result")
                            select new DisplacedModelList() {
                                Name = Convert.ToString(e.Element("name").Value),
                                Address = (e.Element("formatted_address") != null ? Convert.ToString(e.Element("formatted_address").Value) : null),
                                Type = keyword,
                                PhoneNo = (e.Element("international_phone_number") != null ? Convert.ToString(e.Element("international_phone_number").Value) : null),
                                WebSite = (e.Element("website") != null ? Convert.ToString(e.Element("website").Value) : null),
                                Rating = (e.Element("rating") != null ? Convert.ToString(e.Element("rating").Value) : null)
                            }).ToList());
```

If you really want to use LINQ to assign the `List` instead, you need to encompass the `foreach` in the query. You can just replace everything in the body of the `if` with:

```
DisplayInfo.DisplayListed = (from d in Display.Dispaylist
                             from e in XDocument.Load(WebRequest.Create("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/xml?placeid=" + d.Placeid + "&radius=7500&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyA0SrtzNyotUjgqI8cwbfYNrRUkdCoACd8")
                                               .GetResponse()
                                               .GetResponseStream()).Descendants("result")
                             select new DisplacedModelList() {
                                 Name = Convert.ToString(e.Element("name").Value),
                                 Address = (e.Element("formatted_address") != null ? Convert.ToString(e.Element("formatted_address").Value) : null),
                                 Type = keyword,
                                 PhoneNo = (e.Element("international_phone_number") != null ? Convert.ToString(e.Element("international_phone_number").Value) : null),
                                 WebSite = (e.Element("website") != null ? Convert.ToString(e.Element("website").Value) : null),
                                 Rating = (e.Element("rating") != null ? Convert.ToString(e.Element("rating").Value) : null)
                             }).ToList();
```